# pandas: merge two df based on indices with different dtype

Tags: pandas

the following snippet does not work

```
df = df_a.merge(df_b,
                  how='inner', left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

as I believe the indices are of different `dtype`(note `'str'` vs `int` below):

```
df_a.loc['512139']
Out[90]: 
ParSpread       0.000052
CleanPrice    100.099905
Name: 512139, dtype: float64

df_b.loc[512139]
Out[92]: 
Product Type                 CDSIndexTranche
AB_Ref          CDX.IG.21 TR 15-100 07072014
Index              CDX-NAIGS21V1-5Y.Dec.2018
```

how to force the merge or convert either index?

Comment: `df_a.index = df_a.index.astype(int)` ?

Comment: @harvpan put that as an answer!

Comment: @MattMessersmith, done. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do below and make `df_a` 's index as  `int` as well.

```
df_a.index = df_a.index.astype(int)
```